# Histogram (automatic binning)

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions, histograms, smoothing

There are different methods for choosing widths of bins for a histogram, like Freedman-Diaconis rule. In *Mathematica*, without choosing a specific method, with the command `Histogram[data]`, we can produce a histogram for a set of data. My question is: How does *Mathematica* decide which method is better for a given data?

Comment: In the Details section of the help file, it says: "Histogram[data] by default plots a histogram with equal bin widths chosen to approximate an assumed underlying smooth distribution of the values $x_i$." It does not specify exactly how the smoothing is done though. You can specify the method if you want more control.

Comment: @bills Thanks for your feedback. I'm curious how Mathematica decides on this. For example, sometimes it chooses  Scott's rule, and gives this impression that the sample is Gaussian; however, if one specify the method as Freedman-Diaconis, the histogram turns out to be very different. I'd like to know the logic behind Mathematica preference when one doesn't specify any methods.

Comment: @bills In other words, if one does not have any idea about the possible theoretical model behind the data, should one specify the method or just trust Mathematica and doesn't specify any methods.

Comment: Of course the plot looks different when you select the parameters differently. I suspect that the only people who can really answer how it works in Automatic or default mode are at Wolfram. But if you want to know exactly what it is doing then you can always specify the bins yourself!

Comment: @bills That's pretty strange! For example, sometimes histogram is not even calculated according to any named methods in the Documentation. But this is not the case when one uses Kernel Density Estimation. In the Documentation of KernelMixtureDistribution, it says that the default mode is Silverman's rule; thus, one expects a similar comment in the histogram section about the method that it is using.

Comment: Would you give an example where the "histogram is not even calculated according to any named methods in the Documentation" ?

Comment: Nevermind.  I see that with a `CauchyDistribution[0,1]`, there is frequently no match.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for your comment. If you could figure it out, please let me know!

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I don't think one can figure this out empirically.  The choice made seems dependent not only on the shape of the data but also on sample size.  Having someone from Wolfram, Inc. confess is maybe the only possibility.